# how to query hbase based on row keys

Tags: hbase

new to Hbase:
I am working with Hbase now and there is something I can't figure out (for a while now). I was wondering if you 
can help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fussy filter for this type operation.

Comment: fuzzy filter available in the hbase? If so please provide some example query.

Comment: http://blog.sematext.com/2012/08/09/consider-using-fuzzyrowfilter-when-in-need-for-secondary-indexes-in-hbase/

Answer (score 0):

To speed up things as much as possible, HBase doesn't support secondary indexes or alternative query paths. The most common approach is to write the same row data under different row keys (in the same table or in other tables), this generates an overhead when writing but HBase can handle and scale writes very well given a proper row-key design.

This topic is very well explained in the [HBase book](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/secondary.indexes.html), take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

solved this problem.  there are 2 approaches:

1- You can use RowFilter combined with RegexStringComparator. For example if you are missing userId (or you have  partial userId), defind it using RegEx like this:
    String s= ....   //regex for userId
    Filter f = new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new RegexStringComparator(s));
    FilterList filters = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
    filters.addFilter(f);

2-  You can have a small lookup table where contains all userId and channelID      and in the case of missing userId or having partial of rowkey, get all userId or
channelId that match your partial then make several smaller queries one for each matching rowkey.

We combined both and that was successful.

good luck!